# Create Workbook from workbook with macros and send to a different computer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that creates a workbook with some buttons and pulls information from an Excel sheet into it.

The macro works when run on the computer where it was created. If I send the newly created file to a different computer it asks me to update the data sources and if I select don't update the buttons do not work. If I choose to update it it says it can't file the personal.xlsb file.

Why won't the macro work? I guess my main question is if I am creating a new sheet with dropdowns and button, is there a way to have this saved onto the new file with the function they will be using??

Here is some of my code:

```
'Create New Workbook
Function AddNew() As Workbook
Set AddNew = Workbooks.Add()
Wname = ActiveWorkbook.name
Wname = Left(Wname, Len(Wname) - 5)
With AddNew
.SaveAs Filename:=Wname & ".xlsx"
End With
nwrkbksaved = True
End Function

'Run the create new Workbook function and pull information to new sheet
Public Sub TemplateCreate()
Set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook
'Set up template for new workbook
Set NewBook.Workbook = AddNew

'Check to see if New Workbook exists
If nwrkbksaved = False Then GoTo term

'Pull information code

Set btn = NewBook.Workbook.Sheets("sheet1").Buttons.Add(Range("F15").Left, Range("F15").Top, 165, 15)
With btn
    .OnAction = "getData"
    .Caption = "Submit"
    .name = "submitData"
End With

End Sub

Function getData()
'Get data code
End Function
```

Comment: AFAIK - the `Personal.xlsb` is saved to the individual computer.  To find the location, in the Immediate Window of the VBA editor, type `?Application.StartupPath`.  That's where the `Personal.xlsb` resides.  To have this macro work on other computers, the macro should be stored in a module created in that workbook.  Or, share the `Personal.xlsb` file I suppose.

Comment: Data ribbon -> Edit Links will let you see all links you have to other workbooks, and break them if so desired.

Comment: On the other computer in the options of excel, are macros enabled? Have you tried debugging step by step? Where does the error happen? can you show us the code?

Comment: Thank you for all your help everybody! I have updated my question with some of my code, I guess the main issue that I am seen is that since I am creating a new sheet is there a way for the new sheet to save the functions too so it does not need to depend on a macro? Thank you again!

Comment: any idea? :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I was able to figure out this information. After more research this was the answered I was able to come up with hope it helps if you run into this issue:

I used the following link for help http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx

```
Dim ToVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim FromVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim Fname As String

Fname = "Path of bas + bas name.bas"
FromVBProject.VBComponents("module").Export Fname
ToVBProject.VBComponents.Import (Fname)
```

Thank you again for all the help!